# Is -fPIC for shared libraries ONLY?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, compilation, elf

I know `-fPIC` is necessary for shared libraries and know why.

However, I am not clear on the question:

**Should `-fPIC` never be used during building an executable or a static library?**

Comment: My impression—subject to contradiction by the knowledgeable—is that compilers these days generate PIC anyway. Theoretically, PIC is a little less efficient than non-PIC code, but with things like ASLR (address space layout randomization), PIC may well be needed most of the time. I'm thinking primarily of PC desktop systems and larger; the rules could be different in the 'embedded' space. (On a Mac, compiling with `-fPIC` or `-fpic` or with neither gives the same size object code with GCC 7.3.0. But that's not necessarily ELF; the object files are ` Mach-O 64-bit object x86_64`.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Should `-fPIC` never be used during building an executable or a static library?

Never is a strong word, and the statement above is false.

Code built with `-fPIC` is (slightly) less optimal, so why would you want to put it into anything other than a shared library?

Let's start with a static library, which has an easy answer.

Suppose you want to give your users a static library that can be linked into *either* an executable, *or* into a shared library of their own?

In that case you *must* either give them 3 separate archive libraries (one built with `-fPIC` for linking into shared libraries, one built with `-fPIE` for linking into PIE executables, and a "regular" one), or you can give them a single archive library (which must have code built with `-fPIC`).

Now, it could be argued that you should instead give them a shared library, but that forces your end users to distribute 2 binaries, and they may prefer to not do that.

But suppose you want to build a regular (non-PIE) executable. What could be the reason to link in `-fPIC` code into such executable?

Well, suppose you are in the development stage, and don't care that much about optimizing the code yet. Suppose further that you want to test your code as both a shared library, *and* as part of PIE and non-PIE executable.

Under above conditions, you could either compile your code 3 times (with and without `-fPIC`, and with `-fPIE`), *or* you could compile it once (with `-fPIC`) and link it into all 3 of shared library, PIE and non-PIE executable. Doing this saves a lot of compilation time, and some build system complexity.

TL;DR: putting `-fPIC` objects into executables and static libraries has its place, and you should understand the reason why you are doing it (if you end up doing it).

**Update:**

> Code in an object file is always relocatable

Correct.

> is it position-independent code?

No: not all relocatable code is position-independent.

Position-independent code is a *subset* of relocatable code. Relocatable code can have relocations that apply to *any* section. Position-independent code must *not* have any relocations against `.text` (and `.rodata`).

Comment: Code in an object file is always relocatable, is it position-independent code? A static library consists of object files, then, can we say that code in a static library is already position-independent?